# return a uint8_t from a funtion and printing it in the main function

Tags: arrays, c, uint8t

i have a following funtion

```
    uint8_t func(){
        uint8_t key[16] = {0};
        // some operations
        return key;
     }
```

i am calling this function in the main function

```
int main(void){
    uint8_t rcKey[16] = func();
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", rcKey[i]);
    }

}
```

what am i doing incorrectly here? I get invalid initializer error

Comment: First, `key` is not a `uint8_t`, it's an array of 16 `uint8_t` elements.

Comment: You should read this : https://denniskubes.com/2012/08/20/is-c-pass-by-value-or-reference/

Comment: Thank you for the link :) it is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array can't be initialized directly via a function call.  You can only initialize the individual elements as part of an initializer list.

What you can do instead is pass the array to a function to set the relevant values.

```
void func(uint8_t key[]){
    // some operations
 }

int main(void){
    uint8_t rcKey[16]
    func(rcKey);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("%x ", rcKey[i]);
    }

}
```